# pytorch multi gpu speed

Tags: cuda, pytorch

Всем привет.

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался:
Есть риг на 6 GPU. Хочу запустить обучение нейросетки сразу на всех карточках, чтоб быстрее было. Использую Pytorch DataParallel. Если использую одну карту, все отлично. Если указываю несколько, то идет дикая нагрузка на процессор, скорость падает в раз в 10. Процессор - самый дешевый, двухядерный. Напрашивается решение поставить серьезный процессор, но может я что то делаю не так и можно обойтись без изменения аппаратной части ?